# sql how to select row based on json format field value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-json

I have a table ,one of the table filed is json format:

```
my_table

id  json_field

1   { "to_status": 7, "to_status_name": "In Progress", "role": "admin"}

2   { "to_status": 3, "to_status_name": "Completed", "role": "admin"}

3   { "to_status": 2, "to_status_name": "Completed", "role": "customer"}
```

How can I select all rows that "to_status" is 3 or 2 ?

Any friend can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extracted Json values are strings. So you need to test for string values or cast `to_status` extracted values to an integer:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE json_field->>'to_status' in ('2','3');
or
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (json_field->>'to_status')::int in (2,3);
```

But then you can get the same results extracting the `to_status_name`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE json_field->>'to_status_name' = 'Completed';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json_field, '$.to_status') IN (3, 2)

or

SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE json_field->>'$.to_status' IN (3, 2)

to select what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,I have tired both of them ,none of them work for my case.

Comment: Try this one too. SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE json_field->>'to_status' = '3' OR json_field->>'to_status' = '2'